# Unable to login into PluginRegistrationTool - "Plugin Registration Tool stopped working"

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I have 2 different accounts with Dynamics 365 online, few hours back I was able to login with 1 account. But then suddenly when I tried to login with another account, it is throwing errors as below:

[image: Plugin Registration Tool has stopper working!]

And when I clicked on **DEBUG** button and opened it in Visual Studio, it gives error as below:

[image: Error after click on Debug button]

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException   HResult=0x80131604
>   Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler) 
>   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()    at
>   MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object
>   obj)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler) 
>   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs)    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)    at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.MessageBox(HandleRef hWnd, String text,
>   String caption, Int32 type)    at
>   System.Windows.MessageBox.ShowCore(IntPtr owner, String
>   messageBoxText, String caption, MessageBoxButton button,
>   MessageBoxImage icon, MessageBoxResult defaultResult,
>   MessageBoxOptions options)    at System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(Window
>   owner, String messageBoxText, String caption, MessageBoxButton button,
>   MessageBoxImage icon)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Tools.PluginRegistration.CommonControls.ErrorMessageViewModel.ShowErrorMessageBox(Window
>   owner, String message, String caption, String exceptionMessage,
>   UserControl usercontrol, Exception ex)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Tools.PluginRegistration.CommonControls.ErrorMessageViewModel.ShowErrorMessageBox(Window
>   owner, String message, String caption, Exception ex, UserControl
>   usercontrol)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Tools.PluginRegistration.MainViewModel.CreateConnections()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Tools.PluginRegistration.MainViewModel.b__1(Object
>   s)    at
>   MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource
>   commandSource, Boolean userInitiated)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs
>   e)    at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate
>   handler, Object target)    at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target,
>   RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
>   RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender,
>   MouseButtonEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object
>   target)    at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target,
>   RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
>   RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs args)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)    at
>   System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()    at
>   System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
>   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport
>   inputReport)    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd,
>   InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x,
>   Int32 y, Int32 wheel)    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr
>   hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&
>   handled)    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler) 
>   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs)    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)    at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
>   frame)    at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
>   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Tools.PluginRegistration.App.Main()
>
> Inner Exception 1: AdalException: multiple_matching_tokens_detected:
>   The cache contains multiple tokens satisfying the requirements. Call
>   AcquireToken again providing more requirements (e.g. UserId)

As per my initial go through, it looks like there is some token issue here. So I tried even deleting my account from cache, VS2017 and also restarted my machine. But still this issue persist.

**PS:** And when I tried to login with my 1st account which was working previously is no more working and throwing the same error.

Help!

I have already checked below link(s):
[Regarding Plugin Registration Using xxxx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com Credentials](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/039f9483-f1c2-4718-9c56-3f7d66cbea26/regarding-plugin-registration-using-xxxxxxxxonmicrosoftcom-credentials?forum=crm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After clearing **%appdata%\Microsoft\PluginRegistration** it started working.

***For note:*** *We can use PluginRegistrationTool in XRMToolBox too.* *(sharing this as I was not aware before of it.)*

Answer (score 1):

That `Inner Exception` makes more sense, looks like multiple tokens generated & stored for those user profiles in cache.

Following the [answers in SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32000185/7920473), either users UPN got reassigned or some mess happened. PRT unable to overcome this.

If you have not tried, try from a different machine.

Comment: Hi, expecting a reply from you. Thank you. :) And yes, trying it on different machine is not throwing an error but still it is not loading the plugins and I'm unable to proceed further.